# C#: Как программно сымитировать поведение браузера?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, http

Не знаю даже, как именно сформулировать свой вопрос, поэтому опишу всю проблему целиком.
Предположим, у нас есть некая страница в интернете, на которой есть видео-плеер. Нужно с помощью моей программы скачать видео к себе на компьютер. Раньше я делал так: заходил на страницу через браузер, перематывал в конец видео, нажимал "Исследовать элемент", переходил на вкладку "сеть", среди всех запросов выбирал те, которые имеют вот такой вид:
[image: запросы]
И в свою программу из них копировал URL запроса и номер самого последнего "кусочка" видео, после чего она сама генерировала ссылки, начиная с [https://блаблабла/1080p00000.ts](https://%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0/1080p00000.ts) и заканчивая 1080p000NNN.ts, где 000NNN - это последний "кусочек", затем она их всех скачивала в некоторую папку.

Теперь передо мной стоит задача усовершенствовать свою программу. А именно: сделать так, чтобы мне не надо было заходить в браузер для скачивания каждого видео, копировать URL запроса из вкладки "сеть" и т.д. и т.п. И самая главная проблема, которая тут возникает: как моя программа может узнать, по какому URL ей начинать делать запрос для скачивания? Я разбираюсь в работе сайтов на не особо продвинутом уровне, и вот как вижу механизм работы в общих чертах конкретно тут (поправьте, если ошибаюсь):

1. Когда я захожу на страницу через браузер, на сервер сперва посылается простой http запрос, мол, "хочу загрузить страницу",
2. после чего сервер дает браузеру страницу и все файлы, которые с ней связаны,
3. затем браузер видит среди них скрипт *.js, начинает его выполнять,
4. уже сам скрипт говорит браузеру "начни подгружать видео при помощи запроса GET по такому-то URL" (Два замечания: 1 - я так решил, потому что в информации браузера в "причине" указан JS (см. скриншот), 2 - важный ньюанс: самое начало видео начинает подгружаться не в тот момент, когда я нажимаю кнопку "воспроизвести", а когда я только захожу на эту страницу, что немного облегчает мою работу).
5. Потом браузер посылает этот запрос GET по URL-у, который он узнал от скрипта и, соответственно, подгружает видео (что мы и наблюдаем на скриншоте).

И вот мы подобрались к самой сути проблемы: когда я посылаю запросы на сервер из моей программы (на адрес страницы с видео), то, само собой, никакой JS тут не выполняется, и проходит только 1ый пункт всего процесса, соответственно, необходимые URL для получения "кусочков" видео я тоже не получаю. Вопрос: как мне их все-таки получить? Именно из программы на C#.

Для работы с сетью использовал такие классы, как WebClient, WebRequest.

Comment: А зачем вам имитировать поведение браузера? Если у сайта есть API, работайте через него. Если у сайта нету API, скорее всего он не хочет, чтобы вы качали с него информацию программой, и вам следовало бы уважать решение авторов сайта.

Comment: А вообще - можно встроить в приложение браузер и использовать его для этих целей. Использовать можно как "стандартный" IE, так и сторонний (например, тот же Awesomium).